# Return Data Set When Rows In Column Does Not Match

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have have two data sets which I need to compare. There is a column that is the common identifier between the two, but the 2nd data set, which is updated, has more than the 1st data set.

Here is how I extracted the data sets that I need:
[image: Here is how I extracted the data sets that I need]

What I'm trying to do is use columns D/I as the key, then see if columns C/H match. If they do not match I want that data returned or just highlighted.

I'm not very familiar with Excel, but I see the issue, in addition to what I described above, as being since the 2nd data set has more rows, the it will return those as highlighted, which it doesn't need to.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Variations of this question has been asked hundreds of times.

Comment: @findwindow Sorry, I've looked through the questions, but I didn't come to one that I viewed as close enough to what I wanted. That most likely falls on me, but if you could link to me to one you feel is close enough to what I need I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Orions I don't believe I was clear in my question, I've responded to your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you may try

```
=C2=INDEX(H:H,MATCH(D2,I:I,0))
```

and extend / drag this formula to check for more values in `D` column.

This formula results like this:

[image: screenshot-result]

This formula compares values in `D` with values in `I` column and then compares corresponding `C` and `H` values and returns `True` when they match otherwise returns `False`.

In other words: This formula checks if a pair of `Cx-Dx` exactly matches with pair `Hy-Iy` where `x` and `y` are not necessarily equal.

E.g. (refer above screenshot)
`C2-D2` matches with `H2-I2`
`C3-D3` matches with `H4-I4`
`C4-D4` matches with `H3-I3`
and `C5-D5` matches with no pair in `H:I` range.

Comment: thanks for the formula, but my issue is matching the value in D to the same value in I, so D2 and I2 match, so since they match, compare C2 and H2, if they match they highlight or state true. The next is D3 matches with I4, therefore compare C3 and H4, if they match then highlight or state true.

There are some cases where the even though the Dx and Ix value match, the Cx and Hx value do not, in that case I want it to return as false or highlighted a different color.

I hope this explains my predicament better.

Comment: I think I have done the same what you explained me. Please check it with your small sample data. Also, if I done something else, Please provide me a small-sample data and expected output.

Comment: It will pick a `Dx` value and try to find a match in whole column `I:I` when a match say `Ixx` is found then it will check if `Cx` and `Hxx` matches. If they do, `True` is displayed otherwise `False`. Ain't it?

Comment: You're correct. It works as expected, I did not copy the entire formula, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yep, following the logic of the formula makes sense to me. Just being unfamiliar with Excel, I didn't know where to begin. I appreciate the answer and explanation!

Comment: Let me know if you need more help. If you are a beginner, you can spend some time learning [excel function](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions.html), also if you need [excel-vba](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html). You can also Google and learn more.

Comment: In the above answer, I have used two functions `Match` and `Index`, I would suggest you to learn separately what these functions do independently and then learn how they work together.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use COUNTIFS either in a separate column or conditional formatting:-

```
=COUNTIFS($I:$I,$D2,$H:$H,"<>"&$C2)
```

to highlight the first two columns and

```
=COUNTIFS($D:$D,$I2,$C:$C,"<>"&$H2)
```

to highlight the second two columns.